# PL/SQL Use Table Variable in Where Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have a table variable that is being passed into a procedure.  I would like to use the values in a where clause as below, how do I do this.  The first line below is declared in the package definition.  The procedure below is in the package body.

```
type CatalogNos is table of VARCHAR2(100);
PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_  IN CatalogNos, 
                                    Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC
    WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select values from v_catalog_nos_);
END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `CatalogNos` a SQL type (i.e. not declared in a package spec)?  If so:

```
PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_  IN CatalogNos, 
                                    Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor) 
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC
    WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select * from table(v_catalog_nos_));
END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
```

---

> "This SQL gives an error: PLS-00642: local collection types not
>   allowed in SQL statements"

So `CatalogNos` is not a SQL type i.e. it is a PL/SQL type declared in a package spec or body.  The error message is quite clear: we cannot use PL/SQL types in SQL statements.  That's just the way it is.

The simplest solution is to use a SQL type.

```
SQL> create or replace type CatalogNos is table of VARCHAR2(100);    
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

If you really don't want to create your own type (why not?) you can use one of the Oracle built-ins.  Like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS
      (v_catalog_nos_  IN sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll,
       Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC
    WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select * from table(v_catalog_nos_));
END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
/
```

Comment: This SQL gives an error: PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Answer (score 2):

```
create type CatalogNos is table of VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE your_package as
   PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_  IN CatalogNos, 
                                       Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor);
END your_package;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY your_package as
   PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_  IN CatalogNos, 
                                       Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor) AS
   BEGIN
       OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
       SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC
       WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select column_value from table(v_catalog_nos_));
   END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
END your_package;
```

The type definition must be a database object, not part of a package, in order to be used in SQL. Once that's true, you can use the `table` function to reference a variable of that type in the `from` clause.

---

Based on the comment, it seems that I need to re-iterate: in order to reference a user-defined datatype in SQL, you must define the type as a separate object outside of the package.

---

For a user-defined table that contains a single unnamed field, you can use either `select *` or `select column_value`.

Comment: If your first line in my package definition, then the package will not compile.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE **BODY**

Comment: Ok, this all works except for the values keyword in the "IN" statement.  It compiles, if I replace it with a *.

Answer (score 0):

Use || for to concatenate your query with a variable

something like:

```
type CatalogNos is table of VARCHAR2(100);
PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_  IN CatalogNos, 
                                Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
   OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
   'SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC
   WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select values from' || v_catalog_nos_ || ')';
END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
```

Comment: I am still getting compile errors... ORA-00936: missing expression, which points to the beginning of "values".

Comment: The `&` is only used by SQL*Plus on the client side to define (interactive) parameters. This won't work at runtime inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Oracle can't reference a user-defined table type without the use of the `table` function. This proposed solution will not work. In addition, even if it would work, concatenating a variable's value into a DML statement is an extremely poor practice.